# Is Mean Deviation better than Standard Deviation for data mining?

Tags: data-mining, standard-deviation

I just [read this article](http://www.leeds.ac.uk/educol/documents/00003759.htm) and it says Mean Deviation(MD) is more efficient than Standard Deviation(SD) when there are some errors in observations. Like in real practise.

I don't know what 'efficient' means, but according to this, data mining using MD instead of SD might improve model's accuracy if training/test data has some errors. Is it alright to have this assumption?

Comment: The "errors" they're talking about are presumably *outliers*. Absolute deviation is less pulled by extreme values than SD, which makes it less efficient w/ normal data, but more efficient w/ contaminated data.

Comment: Protection against outliers is an important criterion when choosing a statistical model to fit. Fortunately, much progress has been made on this front since Eddington discussed the merits of mean deviation in 1914. This begs the question: [why not use them?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48867/603)